# Custom properties for app part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, properties

I am developing a provider hosted SharePoint app part. I have defined some custom properties for the app part. I am testing the app in a SharePoint online tenant.

On a developer site when I edit the app part the custom properties section comes up.

However for the same tenant, in a Team site when I edit the web part the custom properties section does not come up.

This is the relevant part of my Elements.xml file for the app aprt

```
<!-- Define properties in the Properties element.
     Remember to put Property Name on the Src attribute of the Content element above. -->
<Properties>
  <Property Name="challengeid" Type="string" RequiresDesignerPermission="true" DefaultValue="challengeid" WebBrowsable="true" WebDisplayName="challengeid" WebDescription="Challenge web properties" WebCategory="Challenge web properties" />
</Properties>
```

Has anybody faced a similar problem and would be able to suggest a solution?

Does my online tenant needs some configuration setting?

Comment: Have you tried changing `RequiresDesignerPermission` to false? Have you also tried checking the property while under a user with Site Collection Administrator permissions to rule out permissions in general?

Answer (score 1):

Change `RequiresDesignerPermission` to `false`.

```
<Property Name="challengeid" Type="string" RequiresDesignerPermission="false" DefaultValue="challengeid" WebBrowsable="true" WebDisplayName="challengeid" WebDescription="Challenge web properties" WebCategory="Challenge web properties" />
```